# How to check generic swift array contains an element?

Tags: ios, arrays, generics, swift

How can I examine a generic swift array contain an element, without converting to NSArray?

```
if ([1, 2, 4, 5, 6] as NSArray).containsObject(2) {

    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's this function:

```
contains([1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 1)
```